# Vertically Aligning Text with CSS Tables Not Working

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I was trying to vertically align some text inside a div using a CSS table, but it doesn't work for some reason:

```
<div class="navlink" style="width:150px; display:table;">
<div style="text-align:center; display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Any suggestions on how I can get this code to work?

Comment: Don't use tables to vertically align, the easiest way is to set the line-height of the text to the height of the element you want it centered in. There are also other methods, [here](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, it's simply that you are not using any height for your cell div, so do it like this

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eMkKA/)

```
<div class="navlink" style="width:150px; display:table;">
   <div style="text-align:center; display:table-cell; height: 200px; vertical-align:middle;">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @daniel oh ya that's a valid reason..should take out my answer

Comment: I took it out but I think you are only confusing him with your answer, you set height on the wrong div

Comment: @daniel No I setted on the right div, what if table is more than 150px? so he can set height for td's(div) rather than the whole table, you got me?

Comment: but the table IS 150px in his example, there's no need to change a lot of factors that have no influence on the solution (only confuses the asker)

Answer (score 2):

Works for me, you just put table width instead of height.

`<div class="navlink" style="width:150px; display:table;">`

---> `<div class="navlink" style="height:150px; display:table;">`

Comment: putting width instead of height, means typing 'width' instead of 'height'.

Comment: OP is already using width just see his question, you should say put table height instead of width got me?

Comment: that's what I did, 'you put' is past tense of 'you have to put'

Comment: weird english ;) sounds like you put width...`instead of height` anyways got to go..cya and btw +1..got answer before mine

Answer (score 1):

This is the best answer I've found: http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

This comes up a lot. There's no easy answer.

A quote from the page:

> A FAQ on various IRC channels I help out on is "How do I vertically
>   center my stuff inside this area?" This question is often followed by
>   "I'm using vertical-align:middle but it's not working!"
>
> The problem here is three-fold:
>
> A    HTML layout traditionally was not designed to specify vertical
>   behavior. By its very nature, it scales width-wise, and the content
>   flows to an appropriate height based on the available width.
>   Traditionally, horizontal sizing and layout is easy; vertical sizing
>   and layout was derived from that.
>
> B    The reason vertical-align:middle isn't doing what is desired want
>   is because the author doesn't understand what it's supposed to do, but
>   …
>
> C    … this is because the CSS specification really screwed this one
>   up (in my opinion)—vertical-align is used to specify two completely
>   different behaviors depending on where it is used.

The article goes on to explain that there are two basic methods: absolute positioning, and the line-height method in the other answers.